# is a* the same as (a*)*?

Tags: algorithm, regular-language

Quick question, 
if `a` is a regular expression then is it true that `a* = (a*)*` ?

Is `(a*)*` a valid expression? If it is, then can anyone explain why is it the same as `a*`? I apologize for asking here, but I couldn't find anything via Google.

Comment: Yes, they are the same (theoretically).

Comment: I said that it is theoretically the same, but the code compiled by the regex engine may differ between them, and a* is more efficient than (a*)* in that case, since (a*)* will introduce another level of backtracking.

Comment: @nhahtdh : Does Lex tool not optimized `(a*)*` to `a*`? Because minimization should work?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I don't know about Lex tool. Common regex engine will not do minimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, `a*=(a*)*`  are same. Both generate same language that is string any numbers a's including `null`.

`L(a*) = {^, a, aa, aa...... }  = L ((a*)*)`

Is `(a*)*` a valid expression?

> Yes, this expression is called `REGULAR-EXPRESSION` (I saw you missed the tag). Any Regular Language(RL) can be represented by Regular Expression(RE). A alphabetical way of represent RL.

why is it the same?

> `*`  means repetition any numbers of time (including `0` times).
>
> `a*`  means 0 a, 1 a, 2 a or any number of a.
>
> (a*)* means repetition for all string in `a*` set for any number of time (including 0 times).

Because `L(a*)` means **all string consists using a**. its supper-set of every set consists of strings of a's. and `L((a*)*)` is same.